# Custom numbers in Jhipster jdl

Tags: java, angularjs, jhipster, jdl

I am trying to modify my existing entity using the .jdl file for jhipster.

Now, my requirement for the field is to have only numbers till 1 to 10.

I know this can be easily handled in the fronted or the ts file.

However, is there any way JHipster can do it ??

For example we have maxlength and minlength attributes for a field:

```
entity test {
    label String required minlength(3);
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you read the JDL docs about validations? See https://www.jhipster.tech/jdl/#available-field-types-and-constraints

Answer (score 0):

Thank you... I guess this problem can be solved using the pattern where I can add my custom regular expression.

Issue Resolved

Comment: So your field was a String and not a number? It was not clear in your question